# how to make a winmerge equivalent in linux

Tags: bash

My friend recently asked how to compare two folders in linux and then run meld against any text files that are different.  I'm slowly catching on to the linux philosophy of piping many granular utilities together, and I put together the following solution.  My question is, how could I improve this script.  There seems to be quite a bit of redundancy and I'd appreciate learning better ways to script unix.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1=$1
dir2=$2

# show files that are different only
cmd="diff -rq $dir1 $dir2"
eval $cmd # print this out to the user too
filenames_str=`$cmd`

# remove lines that represent only one file, keep lines that have
# files in both dirs, but are just different
tmp1=`echo "$filenames_str" | sed -n '/ differ$/p'` 

# grab just the first filename for the lines of output
tmp2=`echo "$tmp1" | awk '{ print $2 }'`

# convert newlines sep to space
fs=$(echo "$tmp2") 

# convert string to array
fa=($fs) 

for file in "${fa[@]}"
do
    # drop first directory in path to get relative filename
    rel=`echo $file | sed "s#${dir1}/##"`

    # determine the type of file
    file_type=`file -i $file | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}'`

    # if it's a text file send it to meld
    if [ $file_type == "text" ]
    then
        # throw out error messages with &> /dev/null
        meld $dir1/$rel $dir2/$rel &> /dev/null
    fi 
done
```

please preserve/promote readability in your answers.  An answer that is shorter but harder to understand won't qualify as an answer.

Comment: You are aware of xmerge?

Comment: wasn't, but when i looked it up, couple things *i* didn't like: not FOSS, seemed to use it's own SCM, tho perhaps it works fine on a simple filesystem? solution above is 100% FOSS.  seems there are some 'benefits' to xmerge/xdiff too, like maybe marginally better than meld at comparisons?  better support for moved chunks?  Personally, I've always been satisfied with meld tho.  However looks very slick and nice tho too, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Sorry, actually I meant xxdiff; also have a look at http://www.linuxalt.com/linux-alternatives-to/windows/winmerge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old question, but let's work a bit on it just for fun, without thinking in the final goal (maybe SCM) nor in tools that already do this in a better way. Just let's focus in the script itself.

In the OP's script, there are a lot of string processing inside bash, using tools like `sed` and `awk`, sometimes more than once in the same command line or inside a loop executing n times (one per file).

That's ok, but it's necessary to remember that:

- Each time the script calls any of those programs, it's created a new process in the OS, and that is expensive in time and resources.  So the less programs are called, the better is the performance of script that is executing:

  - `diff`  2 times (1 just to print to user)
  - `sed`   1 time processing `diff` result and 1 time for each file
  - `awk`   1 time processing `sed` result and 2 times for each file (processing `file` result)
  - `file`  1 time for each file
- That doesn't apply to `echo`, `read`, `test` and others that are builtin commands of bash, so no external program is executed.
- `meld` is the final command that will display the files to user, so it doesn't count.
- Even with the builtin commands, redirection pipelines `|` has a cost too, because the shell has to create pipes, duplicate handles, and maybe even creating forks of the shell (that is a process itself). So again: less is better.
- The messages of `diff` command are locale dependants, so if the system is not in english, the whole script won't work.

Thinking that, let's clean a bit the original script, mantaining the OP's logic:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1=$1
dir2=$2

# Set english as current language
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# (1) show files that are different only
diff -rq $dir1 $dir2 | 
    # (2) remove lines that represent only one file, keep lines that have
    # files in both dirs, but are just different, delete all but left filename
    sed '/ differ$/!d; s/^Files //; s/ and .*//' |
    # (3) determine the type of file
    file -i -f - | 
    # (4) for each file
    while IFS=":" read file file_type
    do
        # (5) drop first directory in path to get relative filename
        rel=${file#$dir1}
        # (6) if it's a text file send it to meld
        if [[ "$file_type" =~ "text/" ]]
        then
            # throw out error messages with &> /dev/null
            meld ${dir1}${rel} ${dir2}${rel} &> /dev/null
        fi 
    done
```

A little explaining:

1. Unique chain of commands `cmd1 | cmd2 | ...` where the output (`stdout`) of previous one is the input (`stdin`) of the next one.
2. Execute `sed` just once to execute 3 operations (separated with `;`) in `diff` output:

   - Deleting lines ending with `" differ"`
   - Delete `"Files "` at the beginning of remaining lines
   - Delete from `" and "` to the end of remaining lines
3. Execute command `file` once to process the file list in `stdin` (option `-f -`)
4. Use the `while` bash sentence to read two values separated by `:` for each line line of `stdin`.
5. Use bash variable substitution to extract filename from a variable
6. Use bash test to compare a file type with a regular expression

For clarity reasons, I didn't considerate that file and directory names may have spaces. In such cases, both scripts will fail. To avoid that is necessary enclose in double quotes any reference to file/dir name variable.

I didn't use `awk`, because it is powerful enough that can replace almost the entire script ;-)